# How to transform encoded URL to readable texts?

Tags: url, unicode, unicode-string

It's about Bangla Unicode texts, but can be a problem for any language other than Latin glyphs.
I'm a host of a [Bangla blog](http://nishachor.com) with all its texts and categories in Bangla <sup>(I prefer not to say *Bengali* as because the name of the language is *Bangla* rather than *Bengali*)</sup>.

So the category in Bangla "বাংলা" saying a URL like:
`http://www.example.com/category/বাংলা`

But whenever I copied the URL from address bar and put 'em into a chat panel or somewhere else, it changed with some strange characters, for example:
`http://www.example.com/category/%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A8%E0`<sup>*</sup>

<sub>* it's just an example, not the exact gibberish for the word "বাংলা")</sub>

So, in many cases I got some encoded URLs like above, from where I found no trace which Unicode text they are saying. Recently I'm getting some 404 error logged by one of my plugin. From there I found a URI like:

```
/category/%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A7%9F%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AF%E0
```

I used the Jetpack's Omnisearch to find out any match, but the result is empty. I can't even trace which category that is— creating such a 404.

So here comes the question:

- **How can I transform the encoded URL to readable glyphs?**

Comment: WordPress. Sorry, I din't mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://www.example.com/category/বাংলা
```

isn't a URL; URLs can only contain ASCII characters. This is an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier).

```
http://www.example.com/category/%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE
```

is the URI representation of that IRI. They are otherwise equivalent. A browser may display the ‘pretty’ IRI version in the user interface, but put the URI version on the clipboard so that you can paste it into other tools that don't support IRI.

The 404 address you pasted translates to:

```
/category/স্নায়ুবিদ্য�
```

where the last character is a � because it is an invalid, truncated UTF-8 sequence. (This is probably why the request failed.) Someone may have mis-pasted a partial URI here.

Comment: *A browser may display the ‘pretty’ IRI version in the user interface, but put the URI version on the clipboard so that you can paste it into other tools that don't support IRI.* I actually can't get the point. Yes, you are right, you did a perfect translation of what that is, but, I can't translate 'em. I pasted 'em into Notepad, MS Word with different paste format, browser address bar... but that doesn't appear as স্নায়ুবিদ্য�, they just appeared as those encoded characters. Please clarify the translation process. But thanks for the IRI. :)

Comment: Well, the path/query part of an IRI is translated to URI using standard URL-encoding on top of the UTF-8 character encoding. In Python, you might reverse that with `urllib.unquote('%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE').decode('utf-8', 'replace')`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that can be added to your answer. Any other thought other than Python? I'm a simple PHP programmer. Sorry for the mumbling. :)

Comment: In PHP, [`rawurldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) will URL-decode a path part. You then have a byte string in UTF-8 encoding. Note that for either language this is something that you would only do on split-apart URL components; converting between a full IRI and URI is more work as you have to split up the components and use Punycode on the hostname rather than URL-encoding.

Comment: It can also be done in javascript. Just open Chrome Wrench Menu->Tools->Developer Tools -> Console in Chrome (or equivalent in other browsers).

`decodeURI("http://www.example.com/category/gibberish......")`
or
`encodeURI("http://www.example.com/category/বাংলা")`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using javascript you can do:

```
decodeURIComponent(url);
```

This will make sure the original language is preserved.